# Android - Material EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have created a material edittext( I think it's called so I am new to Android App development). And it is in an Dialog but I it always is focused on start but I don't want it to be focused on start. Can someone help me please??
My code :

```
final android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout Tlay=new android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout(MainActivity.this); Tlay.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); linear1.addView(Tlay); final android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText EditText1=new android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText(MainActivity.this); EditText1.setHint("Material EditText"); EditText1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); Tlay.addView(EditText1);
```

Comment: You have to provide some work that you try: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I guest that you want to hide the softkeyboard when the dialog is shown.
If I'm right then you should try to set the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the View root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              android:padding="16dp"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- Child views -->
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to move the pointer from a EditText to the others. You should watch [the tutotial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5dFSDd8gmQ&t=52s) (at 16:00).

Hope it helps.

Comment: No unfortunately not I already solved this but my edittext hint is like if the user clicked on it and the animation already happened

Comment: If you don't want the animation. You should remove the `TextInputEditText` and using `EditText` instead.

Comment: No I want the animation but it is displayes before the user clicks the edittext

Comment: I think you cannot do it with `TextInputEditText`. If you want you can add one more `TextView`(with the same style with the hint text) above the `EditText` when the `EditText` is focused then you hide the `TextView`. It just an idea. Maybe it's not good